# Recursively localize string in Blazor model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor server application and I'm following [Microsoft's recommended approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#localization) for i18n and l10n together with input validation via a model class.

One of my Blazor components looks like this:

```cs
// MyComponent.razor

@inject IStringLocalizer<Main> _loc

<EditForm Model="@_myModel" OnValidSubmit="@Save">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
    <ValidationSummary/>

    <label for="my-input">@_loc["Title"]</label>
    <InputText id="my-input" @bind-Value="_myModel.Title"/>
    <button type="submit">@_loc["Save"]</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private readonly MyModel _myModel = new();

    private async Task Save()
    {
        // Do something fancy
    }
}
```

The model looks like this:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Main))]
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

And last but not least there are regular C# resource files with the following entries:

```xml
<!-- Main.resx -->
<data name="RequiredError" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The field {0} is mandatory</value>
</data>
<data name="Title" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Title</value>
</data>
<data name="Save" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Save</value>
</data>

<!-- Main.de.resx -->
<data name="RequiredError" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Das Feld {0} ist obligatorisch</value>
</data>
<data name="Title" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Überschrift</value>
</data>
<data name="Save" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Speichern</value>
</data>
```

Now when an error occurs, the error message gets properly translated, but the argument of `RequiredError` is still in English.
So instead of *Das Feld Überschrift ist obligatorisch* I'm getting *Das Feld Title ist obligatorisch*.

How can retrieve a completely localized string, including parameters like `{0}` within `RequiredError`? Is that even possible? Or do I have to add resource entries for every field, e. g. `RequiredErrorTitle`?

Thanks!

Comment: "do I have to add resource entries for every field" - yes, i think you do.  I know what you are trying to do is create a translation for the property "Title", but imaging what would happen if you had 2 properties in 2 different classes called "Title", but in one it referred to a person's title, and in another it referred to a world record title.  These would (probably) be translated as different words in other languages, but in your case, they would be the same word, which would be incorrect.  The way to guarrentee the correct context would be to have the whole sentence translated.